# Lib clipboard doesnot work inside of Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with Angular 1 and clipboard.js in order to copy some data after a rest call.

My code looks like this:

```
clipboard.copy("Some random text"); //works!

service.getEmails(payload).then(function(emails){

    clipboard.copy("Some random text 2"); //error!

}).catch(function(error){

});
```

It just work **outside** the rest call.
The error is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to copy. 
Perhaps it's not available in your browser?
```

About the clipboard lib:

```
bower install clipboard.js --save
```

Do you have any idea of what it is?

Comment: What kind of promise does your `service.getEmails()` return? If it's just an ES6 promise and not made by any library, your browser might not support it yet. [Check the table here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) for supported browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipboard copy function must be invoked in a click handler (called by an user's action), as you can see [here](https://github.com/omichelsen/angular-clipboard), which says:

> "Just remember it has to be in a click event, as clipboard access
>   requires user action.".

Unfortunately, this restriction is related to security issues.